Read compressed DNS message using Rust deku's crate attributes
Is it possible to read compressed DNS messages using Rust deku's crate attributes?
RFC 1035 4 Messages
RFC 1035 4.1.4. Message compression
deku attributes
If it is, how?
I've been using the until attribute, to read until the terminating (NULL) character, but that only works for uncompressed names.
#[derive(Debug, DekuRead, DekuWrite, PartialEq)]
pub struct Message {
    pub header: Header,

    #[deku(count = "header.qdcount")]
    pub question: Vec<Question>,
}

#[derive(Debug, DekuRead, DekuWrite, PartialEq)]
pub struct Question {
    #[deku(until = "|v: &u8| *v == 0")]
    pub qname: Vec<u8>,

    pub qtype: Qtype,

    pub qclass: Qclass,
}

let mut buf = [0u8; 512];
let (read, source) = udp_socket
    .recv_from(&mut buf)
    .await
    .map_err(ConnectionError::RecvError)?;

let qmsg = Message::from_bytes((&mut buf, 0))?;

I am reading a whole message at once.
In case of a compressed name, we'd have to jump to the previously read uncompressed section.
I suppose I could read the header part and questions separately, one by one in a loop, but I'd like to solve it using attributes as that would be more elegant and more concise.
I was thinking about map or cond & seek_from_start combined (but that's not possible). Can I somehow access the already read uncompressed name?
For example, if we query for abc.longname.com and def.longname.com, and the second name uses compression, we'd have to jump after def to the first longname.com and re-read it or re-use it somehow.
